# How to make the notebook show properly some special characters?

Tags: character-encoding

Those special characters, e.g., are `⫺`, `⬇`, `⫽` and `⬃`. They are all displayed as `␴` (well, should be a question mark in a square)

Comment: They work for me. What version / OS are you using?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I am using v11.3 on a Windows 10 PC.